# How to update nested redux state

Tags: react-redux

I have the following structure

```
lookups --> Object
lookups.CATEGORIES --> array of category objects
lookups.TIMEZONES --> array of timezone objects
```

I would like to add new object, which is a lookup object which has lookup_type property. It could be either 'CATEGORY' or 'TIMEZONE'.
Depending on lookup_type, the newly added object has to be added either to CATEGORIES or TIMEZONES object. How this could be achieved?
The structure of lookups object

```
lookups: {CATEGORIES:[{obj1}, {obj2}...], TIMEZONES:[{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}...]}
```

Comment: Please don't edit a solution into your question; post it as an answer instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spread on the nested object or array too:

```
return {
  ...state,
  [action.lookupType]: [
    ...state[action.lookupType],
    action.value,
  ]
};
```

That would add a new item to Categories or Timezone, if you want to replace a value or insert it at an index etc then you should construct the new array how you want it just above the return and pass that instead. Also note that array spread is ES7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after so many trials, the just came up with similar structure. I wish you could see the question earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to pass your lookup object as the payload of an action, which your lookup reducer handles. In the lookup reducer check for the value action.payload.lookup_type and return the state with a new CATEGORIES or TIMEZONES array containing the old values of that array with the lookup object insterted. You should probably check out some redux examples first, if you are unsure how to work with it.

Comment: The question was how to update this complex object in the redux reducer, sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: Can you give a little more details/ how the current implementation of your reducer looks like? If you have access to both arrays in your reducer I do not really see what the issue is. You create a new state from the old state with a new version of your array that you want to update using array.slice().concat(new element) or something like this.

Comment: I have added the structure of the lookups object, the question is, in the action payload I have lookup_type field, which can be either CATEGORIES or TIMEZONES, and depending on its value I update ether CATEGORIES or TIMEZONES array